# gulp.watch task is throwing an error: (FSEvents.framework) FSEventStreamStart: register_with_server: ERROR

Tags: node.js, gulp, gulp-watch

This recently started happening in my gulp.watch task. It was working fine as of two weeks ago.

When I run $ gulp

when it gets to the watch task, it throws the following:

```
(FSEvents.framework) FSEventStreamStart: register_with_server: ERROR: f2d_register_rpc() => (null) (-21)
events.js:85
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
            ^
Error: watch EMFILE
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
    at FSEvent.FSWatcher._handle.onchange (fs.js:1157:26)
```

Per a few suggestions, I have updated node.js, with no luck.

There was also the suggestion that I was trying to watch too many files, so I changed the watch dir to a single file. Still throws the error.

Ive updated gulp to 3.9 globally and locally, along with my dependencies. I even rolled gulp back to an older version on both to see if that worked. No luck.

What could be throwing this on a gulp.watch task?

Here is my gulpfile task:

```
// Watch
gulp.task('watch', function() {

  // Listen on port 35729
  server.listen(35729, function (err) {
    if (err) {
        return console.log(err)
    };
    // Watch .scss files
    gulp.watch('assets/styles/*.scss', ['styles']);
  });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the code you've posted, you've invoked `gulp.watch` but with no instruction as to what should happen when a file changes?

Normally a watch task would trigger the running of another task upon a file change. One would assume that watching changes in `scss` files should trigger `scss` compilation.

```
gulp.watch('assets/styles/style.scss', ['scss:compile']);
// where 'scss:compile' is another defined task for scss compilation.
```

Hope that helps you out and might give you some different output :)